# Laravel project did not start

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-artisan

Good day, I am completely new to Laravel, I have successfully installed laravel-9 on my window PC using XAMMP and composer, the installation was successful and everything worked fine, but when I shut down my computer system and latter wanted to start the project, I started my XAMPP and entered http://127.0.0.1:8000 in my browser's URL bar, but the project did not start. please what should I do.

I have tried to run

```
artisan serve
```

in my terminal, but not still working, please help

Comment: Check XAMMP is everything running correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to resolve it, the mistake I have been making for couple of hours has been that after running `php artisan serve` command, it gives me the port 127.0.0.1:8000, I used CTRL+C to copy, but instead of pressing the command once, I pressed twice which the first time copied and the second time stopped the serve. Thanks to everyone who responded to me.